# PL/SQL how to spool multiple files?

Tags: oracle, plsql, spool

Hy Guys, 
I don't understand how to create a correct script for spool, of multiple files. 
I have read some question about this problem, but I was unable to solve it.

this is my code MAIN_PROCEDURE.sql

```
SET serveroutput ON;
SET trimspool ON;
SET pagesize;

PROCEDURE DINAMIC_SPOOL(file_name VARCHAR2) IS
BEGIN
 dbms_output.put_line('spool '|| file_name || '.txt');
 dbms_output.put_line('bla bla bla');
 dbms_output.put_line('spool off');

END DINAMIC_SPOOL;


BEGIN
 file_name:='test_1';
 DINAMIC_SPOOL(file_name);

 file_name:='test2';
 DINAMIC_SPOOL(file_name);

END;
/
EXIT;
```

Otherwise, there is another method?
I hope in your kind reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that what you try do can work.

SPOOL is a SQLPlus command and as such can only be executed directly by SQLPlus.

DBMS_OUTPUT a PL/SQL package that runs on the server: its output is retrieved by 
SQLPlus and displayed by SQLPlus but it does run on the database server side: and it cannot run SQLPlus commands.

Comment: is there another method?

Comment: Maybe you can try to generate a SQL file with mutiple SPOOL statements: it depends on the context.

Comment: all it's started to this example : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4148458/spooling-multiple-files. I just don't understand the solution

Comment: This example is using DBMS_OUTPUT and PL/SQL code generate a SQL file named  `temp_script.sql` and they run it with `@temp_script.sql` in SQLPlus: as long as the generated SPOOL statements are OK, this is OK.

Answer (score 2):

PL/SQL procedures live on the database server. You write procedures and packages which access the database and can - with some effort, for instance with the package [UTL_FILE](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/arpls/UTL_FILE.html#GUID-EBC42A36-EB72-4AA1-B75F-8CF4BC6E29B4)- write files on the database server.

SQL*Plus lives on the client. It can access the database and spool the output of queries to files on the client. However, it is not a full scripting language, there are no loops, no if/then, no procedures, just plain SQL in in SQL*Plus.

So to speak, SQL*Plus is SQL plus some formatting/spooling extras, and PL/SQL is the (P)rocedural (L)anguage for (SQL).